# Debug web addin for Outlook on MAC error

Tags: macos, outlook, office365

I have developed a new web addin that targets all platforms including MAC (Office 365). 
When I debug the addin on outlook for windows the command button appears on the ribbon -> the task pane opens -> and woks fine!
(This is done with visual studio that opens a ISS server and connects to Office 365 account)
On the Mac I have the latest version of Mac and Outlook and when I debug in visual studio the command button appears in the ribbon, if I click on it the task pane opens with the following error:

**'sorry, we can't load the add-in.  please make sure you have network and/or internet connectivity'**

I have no other errors,  and still the addin works fine on windows.  Also I din't use any method from the javascript api above 1.1.

I am suspecting that I am doing something wrong in manifest, but it's validated -> That means I also imported the manifest directly in Office 365.

Please tell me if I need to provide additional information.  I searched the web and I din't find any solutions for this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you follow this article: [Debug Office Add-ins on iPad and Mac](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/debug-office-add-ins-on-ipad-and-mac). As far as I know this is the way to debug add-ins on Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The add-in manifest has URLs that point to where the add-in is hosted. When you are developing with VS and IIS on Windows, these URLs point to https://localhost:nnnnn. But the MAC will interpret this URL as ITSELF. So you have to enable a web server on the Mac and host the add-in on it and use the same localhost:nnnnn domain.

The other option is to host the add-in on some server (on your network or the cloud) that the Mac has access to. But then you also have to change the URLs in the manifest to match the new hosting location before you copy the manifest over to the Mac.

Comment: I have hosted my content in the cloud. The web server can be accessed from the Mac machine in the normal browser. The manifest is also pointing to this web server and works correctly on my Win10 machine. But on Mac, the pane still shows the dreaded "Sorry, we can't load the add-in" error message. I have followed the steps in the MS article linked in the OP. Any ideas?

Comment: Put the URL of the add-in home page (from the manifest) into a browser on the Mac. It won't run because Office.js won't load, but the home page should at least open. See if it does.

Comment: Thanks. As I shared in my comment, the URL can be accessed successfully in a normal browser on the Mac.

Comment: I found your comment ambiguous. Being able to access the server doesn't necessarily mean the home page will open in the browser. I think the next thing to try is to install the Fiddler tool and see if the Response object when the add-in tries to load has any useful errors.

Comment: Nailed it. It was because I was using `http` instead of `https` in the URL of my website in the manifest. All okay now. Many thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

If this helps anyone, I was getting this error because I was using `http` instead of `https` in the URL of my website in the manifest. As soon as I changed that, everything started working normally.